# Forms Authentication Not Working After Publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, forms-authentication

I have been working on a website project which restricts access to a certain folder to annonymous users and allows access to the folder to those who are logged in.
This has been working perfectly on my development machine.

However since publishing the website and deploying to a web server (Windows Server 2008, IIS7) the forms authentication appears not to be working. Anonymous users are able to access the "restricted" folder.
I have compared the **webconfig** on both the development machine and the web server and they are exactly the same.

I set up the access/restriction to the directory on the development machine using the Web Site Administration Tool built into the .NET Framework using this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/users-and-roles-on-the-production-website-cs). However I understand this tool is localhost only?

Please note: I am not using the asp.net login and registration controls. I am using a custom function in the code behind (C#)

Is this problem caused by the change of location?
The development machine directory: **C:\Users\Megatron\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Osqar - v0.2\OSQARv0.1**
The Web server Directory: **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Osqar**

I am a little lost here so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the web config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="dbConn" connectionString="data source=mssql.database.com; Initial Catalog=devworks_oscar;User ID=myusername;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name="Osqar" loginUrl="/login/login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="60" />
        </authentication>

        <compilation debug="true" />
        <pages /></system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="index.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Where is the authroization rule (access rules)? If you've them in a web.config in sub folder, check the existence of those rules or otherwise post the tags in it

Comment: The rules where created using the ASP.NET web site administration tool (link in question). I then published the website so a sub folder in the InetPub folder of the web server. The authorisation roles are not visible in the webconfig on the development machine but yet it works. Above shows the webconfig from the development machine (working)

Comment: Of course, it works because the default rule is allow all users. Yes, the Website Admin Tool(WAT) adds the rules and the changes made to web.config should be allowed when prompted. or click save all on VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this under `<cofiguraation>` main tag like:

```
<configuration>
 <location path="~/RestrictedFolder">
  <system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
  </system.web>
 </location>
....
```

if you're restricting specific files do:

```
<location path="~/securedpage.aspx">
  <system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
 </system.web>
</location>
```

Do these changes to the web.config in the deployed project

Alternatively as Wiktor suggested use to block anonymous access to the website as a whole

put it under `<system.web>` possibly before or after `<authentication>` tag

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Or create a folder under the root of your project and put secured pages inside that folder. R-click on the folder add new web.config file and put the following under the `<system.web>` tag

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Comment: The final part was the one that got it working. Creating a new web.config for the protected directory. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `authorization` section seems to be missing (?). You should have something like

```
<authorization>
   <deny users="?" />
   <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Without the information about the required level of authorization (deny anonymous users), the application server will let everyone go everywhere.

Comment: I think he has web.config in a sub folder, and according to his question the authentication was working before deployment

Comment: @nuux Yes that correct. It's in the inetpub folder and then inside a folder (Osqar) for that particular project. The web server hosts many websites.
Wiktor Zychla, I have tried this solution but as I am not using the ASP.NET membership controls this will have no effect.

Comment: @Rupert: I asked you if you've another web.config file in the same project. If you've show as otherwise show us full  webconfig tags related to security. One more thing, the rules Wiktor posted are must to use whether you use membership or forms or windows. The question is what kind of rules do you have in your project? You know, rules can overwrite each other if not used properly.

Comment: @nuux I do not have another web config file in the project. The is however one in the parent directory. Below shows the structure.
InetPub > wwwroot > web.config 
InetPub > wwwroot > Osqar --> Web.config
I did not think this would conflict as the Osqar directory is set up as a new website on IIS7? The above webconfig is the full configuration for the Osqar Project. The access roles where configured in the website admin tool. But appear not to be in the web.config (Osqar). I set up to allow only logged in users to access a certain folder. All other pages are public. I hope this makes sense.